# What are the possible reasons for error "The operation has timed out"?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I wrote a small program for downloading files for my client.

The program uses HttpWebRequest to send a POST request and a GET request.

I tested the program on my laptop and on my manager's desktop and it worked well.

However, when I deployed the program to my client's desktop, it gave me this error:

"System.Net.WebException: The Operation has timed out."

**What might be the possible reasons for this?**

The deployment was very simple, I just changed the App.config to set the  target folder's path.

My client's desktop is a server.  Is it possible that firewall blocked my request?
But I was able to accomplish the downloading process through browser on my client's desktop.

Please give me some suggestions if you have related experience.
Thanks

Comment: Oxymoron: "My client's desktop is a server."

Comment: Does the client usually connect through a proxy?

Comment: Here's the order in which I would troubleshoot (since you've provided no code...)

1. Increase the timeout of WebRequest.Timeout (what is the current value?)
2. Check Firewall traffic to see if you notice any ports/requests being actively blocked when the request is made
3. Run [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and look for obvious issues

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I had no control over that device and my client controls the device through remote desktop. I will try to get access to the device and try your suggestions.

Comment: @Singed..Try to find your client's firewall settings and try to connect

Comment: Client told me no firewall or AV

Answer (score 1):

Firewall, Antivirus and insufficient timeout are very possible reasons (in my experience).

Comment: I tested the program on other devices already. So what kind of settings of antivirus or firewall might cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the windows firewall is blocking your application from connecting to the server. Try to add an exception for your app by running `wf.msc`. You will need to add an [outbound rule](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/creating-an-outbound-program-allow-rule-for-windows-firewall-windows-2008).

In order to test quickly whether this is the real reason for your problem, you can try to disable the firewall completely for a short time if it isn't a big security risk.